# But why don't my changes made via `heroku ps:exec` take effect?

Tags: file, heroku

I know Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or
>   restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due
>   to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of
>   normal dyno management.

But when I needed to debug in the dyno, the changes is not reflected at all.

Step to reproduce:

creating some random dyno, then ssh / exec to those dyno:

```
$ heroku ps:exec
Running this command for the first time requires a dyno restart.
Do you want to continue? [y/n]: y
Initializing feature... done
Restarting dynos... done
Waiting for web.1 to start... done
Establishing credentials... done
Connecting to web.1 on ⬢ wiwi123...
```

This is current file content. And We can simply `curl` the request to prove

```
~ $ curl wiwi123.herokuapp.com
hello world
```

But when I try to change it

```
~ $ echo 'another' >> index.php
```

Current content become

```
~ $ cat index.php
hello world
another
```

Somehow the request is not reflected:

```
~ $ curl wiwi123.herokuapp.com
hello world
```

And I know Heroku still refer to this file, because if we remove / rename it. It will be reflected.

```
~ $ mv index.php old.php
~ $ curl wiwi123.herokuapp.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Note for future readers: unlike `heroku run`, which creates a one-off dyno, [`heroku ps:exec` tunnels into an existing dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#getting-started): "By default, Heroku Exec connects to your `web.1` dyno`.